# Symfony2 multi domain landing page

Tags: symfony

I need to attach many domains to a single instance of sf2 ... and based on the requested domain, geopip, language apply a particular view.
And I need it to be easy in the way of adding a new domain and a new "theme".

I've looked into liip, but I'm not that sure that's the best way to do it.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Ok I'm gonna have a deeper look :)

Answer (score 2):

If your application has to manage multiple domains with distinct layout and templates for each one of them, then you've to use [LiipThemeBundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipThemeBundle)

This bundle provides you the possibility to add themes. In your bundle directory it will look under Resources/themes/ or fall back to the normal Resources/views if no matching file was found.

Read the [documentation](https://github.com/liip/LiipThemeBundle/blob/master/README.md) full of examples [here](https://github.com/liip/LiipThemeBundle/blob/master/README.md)